# El front-end muestra datos duplicados después de un TRUNCATE (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, aplicación-web

Recientemente actualicé una tabla de mi base de datos MySQL y me muestra registros duplicados en el front-end, pero cuando hago una búsqueda en la base de datos, solo me muestra un registro. (La base de datos está mostrando la cantidad correcta de datos, el problema es el front-end).

Ejemplo de cómo se muestra ahora mismo en el front-end de manera incorrecta, (fila antigua y nueva a la vez, **siendo el ID un campo único**):

| ID | Nombre | Puntos |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 15 | Juan | 0 |
| 15 | Juan | 250 |
| 27 | Alex | 0 |
| 27 | Alex | 195 |

Estos no son datos reales, pero como se puede ver, la diferencia está en la columna de puntos. **La primera fila con 0 puntos, es el registro antiguo que no debería aparecer en el front-end después del TRUNCATE de la tabla; la fila con 250 puntos, es el nuevo registro**, sin embargo, en el front-end de mi aplicación aparecen ambos registros cuando solo debería aparecer el nuevo.

En DBeaver aparece un único registro, tal y como debería de ser en el front-end. Aun que se muestre aquí como una tabla estática, es una tabla dinámica HTML y JavaScript:

| ID | Nombre | Puntos |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 15 | Juan | 0 |
| 27 | Alex | 0 |

El Update lo hice desde otra base de datos espejo para actualizar esta tabla y de hecho, en ambas bases de datos después de la actualización muestra la misma cantidad de registros en DBaver, pero luego en el front-end es cuando salen los duplicados.

Antes del Update, hice un TRUNCATE para limpiar la tabla y luego rellenar la tabla nuevamente con los datos nuevos. También configuré FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS en 0 para evitar problemas con claves externas pero lo volví a poner a 1 después. De hecho, cuando hice el TRUNCATE, la tabla se limpió correctamente, pero una vez que hice el INSERT con los datos nuevos fue cuando apareció este problema.

No ha habido cambios en el código fuente, solo en la base de datos.

- Motor: InnoDB.
- Consulta realizada: `SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id_usuario in(15, 27)` (Arroja los dos resultados esperados tal y como se muestra en la segunda tabla de este post y no hay conexión entre tablas en esta query).
- Lenguaje del core de la aplicación: PHP 7.4

Gracias :)

Comment: ¿Esos `puntos` se los ha inventado pues?  ¿O alguna vez los ha tenido?  Leete [ask] para aprender a formular la pregunta mostrando un mínimo ejemplo reproducible con código, porque así es muy dificil ayudarte.

Comment: Pregunta reformulada y aclarada.

Comment: ¿Y el código relacionado con la consulta cual es?  ¿Y el que genera la salida de la tabla? ¿De que lenguaje estamos hablando? ¿Usa algun sistema de cache? Por ejemplo Redis? OpCache? claro, desconocemos aun algunas cosas

Comment: No te ofendas, preguntarte por más información y que tengas que esmerarte en redactarla para que los demas podamos ayudarte mejor muchas veces causa que tu mismo te des cuenta del error

Comment: No me ofendo, intento dejarlo lo más claro posible. Solo hay una cosa que no se como comprobar ahora mismo y es el sistema de caché, solo te puedo decir que la base de datos está alojada en un servidor AWS y yo utilizo DBeaver para conectarme a ella. Si pudieras darme alguna indicación de como encontrar esa información te lo agradecería y complementaré más la consulta.

Comment: He añadido más información. De momento es todo lo que he podido encontrar, si hace falta más seguiré investigando.

Comment: Con esa nueva información vamos avanzando... ahora nos falta saber como lo gestionas desde PHP, es decir, ver el codigo que usas en la consulta y como lo lanzas a la salida en HTML.  Con lo que has puesto ya podemos descartar que el problema sea la consulta en si, por lo tanto vamos a centrarnos en la parte del PHP (a ver si la consulta es distinta) y como generas la salida HTML.